# Java InetAddress.getByName returns hostname/ip but it causes ping to fail

Tags: java

I am using correto java 11 JDK

Here is my method:

```
public static boolean sendPingRequest(String host)
{
    boolean value = false;

    try
    {
        InetAddress myip = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + myip);

        if (myip.isReachable(5000))
        {

            System.out.println("Host: " + host + " is reachable");
            value = true;
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("Host: " + host + " is unreachable");
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {

        System.out.println("I can't reach this host: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IO Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return value;
}
```

When I can the method here it fails

```
String myHost = "www.google.com";
sendPingRequest(myHost);
```

Sending Ping Request to [www.google.com/108.177.111.106](http://www.google.com/108.177.111.106)
Host: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is unreachable
Process finished with exit code 0

From reading the documentation it looks like InetAddress.getByName method returns this but it will fail every time unless I can get it to show the host to be the IP 108.177.111.106.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your issue. Here's what I tried:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sendPingRequest("www.google.com"));
        System.out.println(sendPingRequest("74.125.195.106"));
        System.out.println(sendPingRequest("108.177.111.106"));
    }

    public static boolean sendPingRequest(String host) {
        boolean value = false;

        try {
            InetAddress myip = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + myip);
            if (myip.isReachable(5000)) {
                System.out.println("Host: " + host + " is reachable");
                value = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Host: " + host + " is unreachable");
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("I can't reach this host: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Sending Ping Request to www.google.com/74.125.195.105
Host: www.google.com is reachable
true
Sending Ping Request to /74.125.195.106
Host: 74.125.195.106 is reachable
true
Sending Ping Request to /108.177.111.106
Host: 108.177.111.106 is reachable
true
```

Perhaps you were having network issues?

Comment: it works when I do it via command line just not in java...I could be wrong but this line of code InetAddress myip = InetAddress.getByName(host); seems to return more than the ip and instead returns www.google.com/74.125.195.105, if you tried to ping www.google.com/74.125.195.105 it would fail...

Comment: the ping command (as in the one in command line) would indeed fail, but as you can see above the return of www.google.com/74.125.195.105 isnt a problem since I was getting it too and it wasn't an issue.

The .isReachable method doesn't use the ping command to send it's ping requests, but has its own implementation. The hostname/Ip format is just the string representation of the InetAddress. It only uses IP to actually do its ping. 

Im not sure why Java would be failing if you can ping with command line, but it definitely isnt what you wrote in your code.